# Query string of referrer URL

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Using php or javascript or regex, is there a quick (one-liner hopefully) to get the query string from the previous (referrer) URL?

Example,

User is at

```
www.sample.com?one
```

Then clicks link to go to

```
www.sample.com?two
```

From page two... I want to know the previous query string "one."

Comment: Perhaps you can use sessions to store `one`

Comment: In javascript you can use `location.search` but you'll have to parse it

Comment: And in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Most of these were not the previous URL... I needed the referrer. There is a great one liner below in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This perhaps?

```
var qs = document.referrer.split('?')[1] || '';
```

Looks like it's a contest :)

```
var r = document.referrer,
    indexOfQm = r.indexOf('?'),
    len = r.length;

/(?:[^?]+)\??(.*)/.exec(r)[1];

r.split('?').shift().pop() || '';

r.slice(indexOfQm === -1? len : indexOfQm - len + 1);

r.substring(indexOfQm === -1? len : indexOfQm + 1);

r.replace(/^.+?(?:\?(.*)|$)/, '$1');

r.split('').slice(indexOfQm + 1).join('');

[].reduce.call(r, function (res, c) {
    if (res.found) res.qs += c;
    else if (c === '?') res.found = true;

    return res;
}, { found: false, qs: '' }).qs;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the referrer string on the server side.

If using PHP, it's as simple as this:

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

Then just split the string on the '?' sign to an array and you have the query-string at array index 1

Answer (score 2):

Here’s one one-liner per line:

```
document.referrer.split("?").slice(1).join("?")
document.referrer.substring(document.referrer.indexOf("?") + 1)
/(?:\?(.+))?/.exec(document.referrer)[1]
```

`referrer` is not a good thing to rely on, though; people can and do turn them off. (I do.) Consider cookies or local storage.

Comment: He wants the query string without `?` as far as I can see.

Comment: @plalx: Oh, only the last one doesn’t do that. Thanks.