# Html getElementById to change an element in another html file

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML and Javascript, and for an assignment I need to get a button to change an element to another HTML file.

Here is my code:

**main.html**

```
</head>
    <script src="testscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="button1()">Function 1</button>
</body>
```

**testscript.js**

```
function button1(){
var value = confirm("Press anything");

if(value == 1){
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "Ok";
    window.location.assign("button1.html");}   
}
```

**button1.html**

```
<body>  
    <p id="abc"></p>
</body>
```

So basically, button1() gets called from main.html and needs to change the value of an element in button1.html.

A similar example is illustrated here: [(link)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html). I have also tried outerHTML but it doesn't work either. Is this not possible? I can't find anything online.

Note: **My html and js files have to be separated.**

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Inline event handling is not a best practice; instead give your button an ID and attach an event handler to it.

Second: Any DOM manipulations should be handled *after* the DOM has loaded; either move your JS to the bottom just before the closing body tag, or use `window.onload`.

So, if you have the following HTML:

```
<button id="f1">Function1</button>
```

...then, you should have something like this in your JS file:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('f1').onclick = function() {
    var value = prompt("Press anything");
    };
};
```

To pass data between pages [you can use cookies, localStorage or URL query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213788/how-to-pass-variable-value-between-different-html-pages-in-javascript).