# How do I store text box values for later use with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, storage

So I have a "quick register" kind of widget in my footer with only first and last name text boxes. I also have a button that redirects to the actual registration page after clicked. My intentions are to carry the information inputted into the text boxes over and fill the matching first/last name text boxes on the registration form.

```js
document.querySelector(".footerSignUp").onclick = function () {
var footerFirst = document.querySelector(".footerFirstName").value;
var footerLast = document.querySelector(".footerLastName").value;
alert(footerFirst,footerLast);
location.href = " http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/register/ ";
};
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-text footerFirstName" name="billing_first_name" value="Firstname" />

<input type="text" class="input-text footerLastName" name="billing_last_name" value="Lastname" />

<input type="button" value="Sign-up" class="footerSignUp" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable value between different html pages in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213788/how-to-pass-variable-value-between-different-html-pages-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to append the values as query parameters and have logic in your redirected url to extract that info and populate the input elements.

**Page with the click event**

```
document.querySelector(".footerSignUp").onclick = function() {
  var footerFirst = document.querySelector(".footerFirstName").value;
  var footerLast = document.querySelector(".footerLastName").value;
  var url = getUrl(firstName, lastName);
  location.href = url;
};

function getUrl(firstName, lastName) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/register/';
    var params = "firstName=" + firstName + "&lastName=" + lastName;

    return [url, params].join('?');
}
```

**Extract in registration page**

```
// In the registration page extract the params

function extractParams() {
   var url = location.href;
   // Extract the query params from the url
   var queryParams = url.split('?')[1];
   // Extract individual params
   var params = queryParams.split('&');

   params.forEach(function(param) {
       var data = param.split('=');
       var key = data[0];
       var value = data[1];
       var selector;

       if(key === 'firstName' && value) {
           selector = '.footerFirstName';
       } else if(key === 'lastName' && value){
           selector = '.lastFirstName';
       }

       if(selector) {
           document.querySelector(selector).value = value;
       }
   });
}

extractParams();
```

**Edit**

On page 2 get the `url`

```
var url = location.href;
var params = url.split('?')[1];

//And then set the new redirect
location.href = newLocation + '?' + params;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Your code is doing what you intended, I can see the appended values in the URL. All I had to tweek was the variable names because they changed from 'footerFirst' to 'firstName', but no big deal. However, i forgot to mention I have a page in between the footer sign up and the registration form page. It's a page that asks the user if the account will be for company or personal. Is there anyway to get the values in the url to stay there for 1 more redirect?

Comment: It would have to insert to the the following URLs 'http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/register/personal-account-registration/' & 'http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/register/company-account-registration/'

Comment: @SebG Glad to have helped :)

Comment: You will have to get the `location.href` and then split it using `?` and the append it to the new location for the 2nd redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`.

**Code snippets may not work here, because of cors/sandbox**.

```js
function storeData(){
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
  var userData = {
    'firstName': firstName,
    'lastName': lastName
  }
  localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='firstName' class="input-text footerFirstName" name="billing_first_name" value="Firstname" />

<input type="text" id='lastName' class="input-text footerLastName" name="billing_last_name" value="Lastname" />

<input type="button" onclick="storeData()" value="Sign-up" class="footerSignUp" />
```

Then, on the page with registration form:

```js
window.onload = function getUserData(){
  var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
  localStorage.clear()
  console.log(userData);
}
```

It will store the saved user's `firstName` and `lastName` in the `userData` variable.