# How to pass the value that I clicked to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, ionic3

I am new to ionic, and I have design an ionic application, I want to pass the first page value to the second page. I will attach 2 photo to explain it more clearly.

This is the first picture

**First Page**

[image: First Page]

Once I clicked the white box button on the first page, I want the icon to be appear on the second page like this.

**Second Page**

[image: Second Page]

If I click Electricity on the first page, the icon on second page will show what I clicked on the first page, the icon what you see is I hard code it. I have no idea how to make it works, does anyone know how to make it works ?

This is my code for the first page button,

```
<ion-col col-6 style="text-align:center;" >
  <button ion-button (click)="problem()" class="divButtonBox">
   <ion-icon class="logo-flash" name="flash"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-col>
```

Here is the TS for problem();

```
problem(){
  this.navCtrl.push(ProblemPage)  
}
```

Here is the code for viewing second page, I hard code it because I don't know how to pass the value or string.

```
<ion-col col-5 style="text-align:center;">
    <ion-icon name="flash" class="logo"></ion-icon>
</ion-col>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213788/how-to-pass-variable-value-between-different-html-pages-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using ionics [`NavController`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/). You can simply add optional data to the `push()` call:

```
this.navCtrl.push(ProblemPage, {
  problemType: 'electricity'
});
```

And you can retrieve it on the `ProblemPage` like this using [`NavParams`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/):

```
export class ProblemPage {
  public problemType;

  constructor(private navParams: NavParams) {
   this.problemType = navParams.get('problemType');
  }
}
```

Comment: David, thanks for answering, what if I have 6 type of parameter, how can I set it to dynamic ?? if the user does not click on the first button , but the second or last button, how the problemType become dynamic and pass the value that the user click ??

Comment: You have to pass that to your `problem()` function as a parameter. But thats very basic programming skills. You should read a few starter tutorials.

Comment: David, I know how to pass to my problem(), but every button they clicked I use it to call the problem() function, so I need to let the program know the user is clicking which button , so that the problem page can show the exact value that the user clicks. Sorry for misleading you, I did not clarify my question clearly.

Comment: Okay, I solved that things. I figure it out. Thanks David !! Love you so much ! ~

Comment: I'm you could figure it out! Please be so kind and accept (or upvote) the answer if it helped you solve the problem.