# Array values changed by Javascript function resets when changing HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blank array in my javascript called `Counter`. When I run the `test()` function, I want it to add a value to the array and change HTML pages. But while in the second page, if I `console.log(Counter)`, it appears as blank.

How can I add a value to the array while maintaining it when changing pages?

**Javascript**

```
var Counter = [];

function test() {
    Counter.push("1")
    window.location.replace("page2.html")
}
```

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213788/how-to-pass-variable-value-between-different-html-pages-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Create a new text file and add your Counter variable to it...

```
 var Counter = [];
```

...and then rename the text file to Shared.js

Now add this line to all HTML pages that need this variable, in their HEAD section...

```
<script src="Shared.js"></script>
```

All pages should now be able to share this array as well as any other variables you may wish to add to Shared.js.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `window.location.replace("page2.html?Counter=" + Counter)`

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't saved when refreshing or going to a different web page.
If you want to save them, you can try saving them in Cookies, or, an easier solution, **HTML5 Storage**.

First, you transform your variable into a string using JSON: `var CounterString = JSON.stringify(Counter);`

Then, you save the string in HTML5 Storage: `localStorage.setItem("Counter", CounterString);`

After that, wherever you want to access the Counter, just use: `Counter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Counter"));` (It gets the Counter String and parses it back to a JavaScript Object.

Full Code:

```js
var Counter = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Counter"));

function test() {
    Counter.push("1")
    var CounterString = JSON.stringify(Counter);
    localStorage.setItem("Counter", CounterString);
    window.location.replace("page2.html")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript execution context is limited to a single page. In other words, all your JavaScript variables are lost when you navigate away from the page.

One solution is to use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage.).

`LocalStorage` allows you to save short amount of data which persists across sessions (same domain). You can save the stringified array to the `localStorage` and retrieve it back when loading the page.

```
//Save array to localstorage
window.localStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(arr));


//Retreive item from localStorage
arr = window.localstorage.getItem('arr');
arr = JSON.parse(arr);
```

There are other solutions such as passing the stringified array value as a ural parameter to the next page. But I guess `localStorage` is less work.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without changing the array into a string? I still need to use it for other calculations.

Comment: The original array stays intact. String conversion is just for saving it in the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the sessionStorage.

PageOne.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page One</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="test()">Click me!</button>
        <script>
        var Counter = [];

        function test() {
            Counter.push("1");
            sessionStorage.setItem("counter", JSON.stringify(Counter));
            window.location.replace("PageTwo.html");
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PageTwo.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var counter = sessionStorage.getItem("counter");
            console.log(counter);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```