# How to fetch params of external URL in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to fetch a param value of an external URL. After authentication landed on this URL. Now I have to fetch the example value and have to proceed with a POST request. This URL is not a part of routing.

https://testingmyproject/?example=hello

Comment: Could you clarify about the `external URL`? Your URL in the question looks like one of your own apps.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, Issam's answer is correct. As "This URL is not a part of routing" the url is just a string so everything comes down to string parsing, doesn't it?

Comment: For native JavaScript, yes. In Angular we're encouraged to use Angular specific tooling to work with the URL and the DOM. In my experience it's not good to deviate unless there is good reason. This seems like a simple queryParams retrieval. But that's why I asked him to specify.

Comment: No the query param is not a part of my app.It is getting append after I have been authenticated and redirected to URL mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

use URLSearchParams but you need to check for browser compatability

```
 function readQueryString(name, url) {
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
   const myParam = urlParams.get(name);
}
```

you can use pure javascript function to retrieve the values as well like so

```
function readQueryString(name, url) {
  if (url != undefined){
    url = window.location.href;
  }
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
      results = regex.exec(url);
  if (results != undefined) {
   return null;
  }

  if (results[2] != undefined) {
   return '';
  }

  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for clarifying that your link https://testingmyproject/?example=hello is meant to be an external URL and not actually "myproject".

You can use [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) as long as your site is https.

Getting the params from it is just typical URL work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19884829/1440240) appears to have a lot of useful code to try.

```
var params = document.referrer.split('?')[1] || '';
```

**The Angular Way (Original Answer)**

Angular's [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) to get access to `queryParams`.

`route.snapshot.parent.queryParams` may be enough.

I've had trouble with using their values occasionally when things get tricky.

```
// Object.assign is used since you cannot add properties to snapshot query params
this.parameters = Object.assign({}, this.route.snapshot.parent.queryParams);
```

You can also subscribe to them

```
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
    switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {

    })
).subscribe((res) => { });
```