# How to get QueryParams from redirected URL in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, query-string

I have a certain url where I have to redirect users for authentication and I will get a code as query params.

Suppose I redirect user to `http://someurl.com` and it will be redirected to another url and I will get the code as query params like `http://anotherurl.com?code=1234`

So I am using `window.location.href="http://someurl.com"` to redirect user
But how can I get this code in Angular?

Comment: you mention this **These url are not a part of my angular application or a angular component. These are different urls** several times so where is the starting point you are in angular application, You redirect user to external URL ?? is this the scenario ?

Comment: The starting part is `http://myApplication.com/SomePage`, I have to redirect users to `http://authurl.com/?access_url=http://myApplication.com` and then it will redirect me to `http://myApplication.com?code=1234`. It will send me code as queryparams

Comment: When redirected to your application `http://myApplication.com?code=1234` you could simple use:

`private code: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((queryParams: ParamMap) => {
       this.code = Number.parseInt(queryParams.get('code'));
    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

To Redirecting the Router to Another Route:
We may configure the router to redirect to a named route by default:

```
    export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'component-one', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'component-one', component: ComponentOne },
  { path: 'component-two', component: ComponentTwo }
];
```

To Read Route Parameters :

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'product-details',
  template: `
    <div>
      Showing product details for product: {{id}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class LoanDetailsPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

       // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: These url are not a part of my angular application or a angular component. These are different urls

Answer (score 0):

```
in Routing file define routes like below
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'planner', component: PlannerTrackerComponent },
  {path: '' ,  component: PlannerTrackerComponent },
  {path: 'planner/:id' , component: PlannerTrackerComponent}
];

in Ts file :
 constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }
 ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: These url are not a part of my angular application or a angular component. These are different urls

Comment: obviously those only for example, you can give you urls and I have just showed how to get the id from url

Answer (score 0):

Using ActivatedRoute you can get query params like this

```
code: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   console.log('Called Constructor');
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.code = params['code'];
    });
}
```

Comment: These url are not a part of my angular application or a angular component. These are different urls

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884803/query-string-of-referrer-url/19884829#19884829